# Having troubles with character set

Tags: html, utf-8

Very, very simple example code, standard HTML only (no PHP, nothing) showing up as strange characters instead of proper international characters

Have tried multiple browsers (Chrome, even ugly IE), tried on local IIS server and also on a hostgator site. Yet I get the diamond with the question mark in it instead of a proper international char.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Réunion</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

(Oddly enough, the example code i pasted in shows up correctly.) So... how can that really simple example possibly fail to produce the expected results? What am I missing? (I have my palm-forehead slap all prepped, some one give me the "you idiot!" answer please!!)

Comment: Please show the bytes (in hex) for word.

Comment: Ok... the example I posted is distilled from the actual problem. The actual problem has to do with data coming from a MySQL database and simply getting passed through the code to the screen. The "reunion" was captured from the data stream and then I put it in increasingly simple test code cases until I got down to this, and it still does the same thing. So I don't think the page encoding has anything to do with it, nor the actual hex of the string. Unless I'm missing something there?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can go wrong here...

Your meta tag says `UTF-8`, but are you sure that your text editor is actually saving the file in UTF-8?

Is your server sending out a conflicting character encoding in its Content-Type HTTP header, such as `Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`?

Is the software that you're using to transfer the file to your server correctly honoring the character encoding of the HTML file?